# What storage class is a static inside a function and why?

Tags: c++, storage-class-specifier

If I'm using a singleton pattern (yeah, I know - they're usually bad)... and I had an instance function like so:

```
MySingleton* Instance() {
    static MySingleton instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

what storage class is `instance`?

I'm reading "Programming With POSIX Threads by David R. Butenhof", and I came across text that said:

> Most of the time you'll probably declare condition variables using the extern or static storage class at file scope, that is, outside of any function.  They should have normal (extern) storage class if they are used by other files, or static storage class if they are used only within the file that declares the variable.

Since this static is inside a function, is it auto? or is the class different because of the static key word?

If I moved the 'instance' variable to be static and global (not in any function) in its file - could I still give a reference to it to another file, or would that not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the author has conflated storage duration and linkage, although the advice what keywords to use is correct.

Your function-scope variable `instance` has static storage duration. Without the `static` keyword it would have automatic storage duration.

An object at file scope *always* has static storage duration (well, or thread storage duration in C++11 with keyword `thread_local`). Using the `static` keyword at file scope gives the object *internal linkage*, `extern` gives it *external linkage*, they don't affect storage duration.

Describing something has having "static storage class" is correct, since `static` is a so-called "storage class specifier", but it's not the whole story since the meaning of `static` in file scope is different from the meaning in function scope.

You can pass around a reference to an object with static storage duration to code from other translation units. It doesn't matter whether it has file scope or function scope, and it doesn't matter what its linkage is. "They should have normal (extern) storage class if they are used by other files" just means that a global needs external linkage if other files are going to refer to it *by name*, since a global name with internal linkage refers to a different object in each TU. Technically it's the name that has linkage, not the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - you hit the spot with what was confusing me :)  Do you know a good resource for learning this stuff? I haven't come across it (in any significant manner) in any of my C++ books - just odd references which aren't substantial enough to learn from.

Comment: @w00te: the standard. Read the full sections on "storage duration", "linkage", and "storage class specifiers". Then re-read the section on linkage, because although linkage itself is quite simple, the rules for multiple declarations with different storage class specifiers confuse the heck out of me. Then finally, it's probably worth reading something implementation-specific about how DLL import/export is handled by your compiler, since although it's not the same as linkage it is very closely related.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my reading list - though it sounds like it might put me in fetal position :)

Answer (score 4):

`instance` has an Static storage class since it is qualified with the `static` qualifier without it it would be `automatic` variable with local scope.
static variables declared at file scope have internal linkage and you cannot use them across different files.
if you want to declare a global variable which can be used across files then you need to use `extern` which gives the variable external linkage.

Comment: So, instance (in the singleton example) can be used across files, but if I declared it at file scope I couldn't use it across files?

Comment: @w00te: No. a static inside function has scope limited to that function only, while a static in a file has scope limited to that file only.

Comment: So, does this singleton method not work, or is it okay because the pointer is returned to the memory location, and we're certain that location persists because its static?

Comment: Actually I figured it out - thanks :) +1 for the helpful solution.

Comment: @w00te: Since the variable is static it is assured to be alive throughout the life of the program and since you return it explicitly as return value it can be used across different files(Translation units)

Answer (score 1):

In general Singleton pattern is used in projects so that there will be only one instance used in that project. like DB connection pool generators or configuration. Singleton is used in the following way:The instance which will always be called must be static and private in the class, the constructor of the class must be private, the getInstance function must be public.
Let's see below:

```
/**
 * @author harzumanian
 *
 */
public class LogManager {

    private File file = null;
    private static LogManager logger = null;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private LogManager() {
        file = new File(Constants.PLUGIN_LOG);
    }

    public static LogManager getLogger() {
        if (logger == null) {
            logger = new LogManager();
        }
        return logger;
    }
}
```